# Como dar um UPDATE trocando \\ por \?

Tags: mysql, string, sintaxe

Eu estou tentando realizar um UPDATE para trocar o `\\` por `\` , como no SQL abaixo:

```
UPDATE `post` SET `descricao`= replace(descricao, '\\','\');
```

Me falaram que o MySQL não aceita expressão regular no `UPDATE` e que eu deveria usar o `REPLACE`, mas ele da erro de sintaxe. Enfim, como eu resolvo isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A barra invertida tem significado especial nas *strings*. Ela indica que o próximo caractere é especial e não deve ser tratado como um caractere normal. Ao mesmo tempo ele pega algum caractere especial e transforma em caractere normal. Quais são os caracteres especiais?

Obviamente que as aspas são especiais para encerrar a *string*, portanto se você quiser que aspas sejam parte do texto a única forma de fazer isso é colocando uma barra invertida antes para dizer que é um caractere normal e não está querendo encerrar o texto.

Também se você quiser que uma barra invertida seja um caractere normal precisa colocar uma barra invertida antes dela para que a primeira tenha o significado especial e a segunda seja o caractere normal.

Então quando coloca só uma barra invertida e depois vem aspas ela não está encerrando o texto (que é necessário) e causa o erro de sintaxe. Para funcionar precisa colocar a barra invertida duas vezes, assim só uma será considerada a barra como caractere e aí fecha aspas normalmente sem erro.

No outro não há erro de sintaxe mas há erro semântico do que deseja. Como tem duas barras só uma será considerada pelo mesmo motivo acima. Então se quer representar duas barras invertidas como caracteres normais precisa colocar 4 delas assim as duas primeiras formam uma barra real e as duas seguintes formam a segunda barra real. Assim:

```
UPDATE post SET descricao = replace(descricao, '\\\\','\\');
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Update/EscpeString.sql).

Não estou dizendo que isso resolve satisfatoriamente o que deseja porque nem tem detalhes e não é o foco da pergunta.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela a sua explicação e ajuda, além de me esclarecer ela me ajudou muito!!!

Comment: @j você sabe que pode votar em tudo no site também, além de aceitar respostas dadas em perguntas suas?

Answer (score 0):

tente isso.
o replace ele faz o seguinte, pega o primeiro parâmetro e troca pelo segundo parâmetro informado. ou seja onde tiver \ vai trocar por .
UPDATE post SET descricao = replace(descricao, '\','\');